# ES6 Parent class overrides child prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I decided to write ES6 class for Express server, but extended Express overrides child prototype, and there is no way to use methods and props that defined outside constructor. See code:

```
import Express from 'express'
export default class Server extends Express {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options.expressOptions || {})
        super.use(cookieParser()) // TypeError: (intermediate value).use is not a function
        this.use(bodyParser.json()) // This definition works cause of overridden prototype
        this.use(Express.static('static'))

        this.test() // TypeError: this.test is not a function
        this.test1 = '123' // Contains in Server final prototype
    }
    test() {
        console.log('test')
    }
}
```

And problem with super class definition. I don't know how to save child prototype. It's will be very precious if you help.

Comment: What is `Express`?

Comment: @Bergi, I've updated this topic, Express is npm dependence, web server framework.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this error is often caused by the automatic semicolon insertion rules. Can you try with semicolons after each statement in the constructor?

Comment: @lonesomeday when I build the project, semicolons inserts automatically, that's true. And I've tried your solution too, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: @AlexeyS. OK, I didn't know that the `express` package exports its constructor...

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't, which is indeed the problem. (I just checked!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked again at this, I see the problem.

**`express` is not a constructor.**

You are treating `express` as if it were a constructor that you call using `new Express`. This is not how it works: you just call it with, for example, `const app = express()`. In fact, `express` is a function ([here's the source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L37)) that creates the object for you, in an old-fashioned (non-ES6) way.

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to subclass any of the core Express objects. You could, I guess, use classes to wrap the Express framework objects, but that doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Comment: Yes: `function SubclassibleExpress(...args) { return Object.setPrototypeOf(express(), new.target.prototype); }`